# Como setar o Index de uma List para iniciar em 1 em vez de 0 quando populada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, lista

Sempre que populo uma lista no C#, como no exemplo abaixo, à medida que vou adicionando itens, eles ficam dispostos iniciando pela posição 0 no *index*. Se eu adicionar 5 itens à minha lista, terei as posições 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4. Preciso fazer com que o *index* inicie com 1 e ficando na ordem 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5.

Isso é possível?

```
List<PessoaContatoViewModel> lista = new List<PessoaContatoViewModel>();
lista.Add(pc);
```

Comment: Por que precisa? Não vejo motivos para isto.

Comment: Preciso, pois estou criando alguns campos dinamicamente e  estou testando uma maneira de passar uma List com as posições prontas @Maniero.

Comment: Explique melhor, ainda não vi motivos, não faz a diferença começar no 0 ou 1, você consegue fazer tudo o que precisar. Dê um exemplo real.

Comment: @MasterJR Não é só controlar o índice real separado? Se os índices iniciam em 0 e você precisa controlar como 1 é só incrementar em 1 cada índice...

Comment: Pense em um tela que vc precisa inserir campos de telefone dinamicamente sem usar JS. Imagine que vc já tenha dois campos criados... então, o índice está em 1, pois a lista vai de 0 a 1, então logicamente, vc tem dois itens.

Comment: ...Se eu add um terceiro field o índice estará em 2 e se eu passar uma list com um modelo de fone a posição dela estará em 0 e eu precisarei passar com índice 2. Por isso preciso fazer isso para poder testar se funciona... Sei que vc poderia dizer: Ah, mas vc poderia simplificar isso usando JAVA Script..., mas eu não domino muito e vi problemas ao criar campos usando JS na parte das validations, pois não funcionam e tem que fazer um monte de modificações que no meu caso demorariam...

Comment: Não entendi absolutamente nada. De qualquer forma, não consigo imaginar nenhum motivo pra querer fazer isso.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk Se eu conseguisse setar isso, já bastaria e resolveria meu problema.

Comment: @MasterJR Mas não consegue, não existe essa opção. Eu pergunto qual o objetivo porque não há motivos para fazer isso... Entendendo o motivo inicial eu poderia te indicar uma solução.

Comment: Entendi... De todas as, obrigado @Maniero :)

Comment: Já pensou em adicionar um item vazio na sua lista antes de preencher ela, onde o mesmo irá tomara a posição de 0. E quando for iniciar o `loop for`, começar a contagem do index pela contagem 1?

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível, e nem é porque não faz sentido, não é algo necessário. Usando seu exemplo, vamos supor que tenha um i que começa em 1, basta acessar subtraindo 1 e está resolvido, acessará o primeiro elemento como quer usando uma variável que começa em 1:

```
var i = 1;
var lista = new List<PessoaContatoViewModel>();
lista.Add(pc);
Write(lista[i - 1]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/IndexOffset.cs).

Se não conseguir entender isso ou resolver a questão, ou explicar se não é isto que precisa, aí o problema é estar tentando fazer o que está, neste momento, além do que tem capacidade de fazer e não é uma resposta aqui que resolverá o problema. Aí a sugestão é começar fazer coisas mais simples, construir o conhecimento passo por passo, para chegar no ponto que precisa, pular etapas não ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero! Infelizmente, já que não dá para mudar, buscarei outra solução. Abraço!